# Testing for samples being drawn from identical Bernoulli r.v.'s

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

Suppose that I have a sequence of size $n$: $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, $x_i\in\{0,1\}$.  My null hypothesis is that all $n$ members of the sequence are drawn  independently from an identical Bernoulli distribution with $P(x_i=1)=p$.  My alternate hypothesis is that the $j$-th subsequence of length $m$ is drawn independently from an identical Bernoulli distribution with $P(x_i=1)=p_j$ for $(j-1)m<i\leq jm$, $1\leq j \leq n/m$ such that there exists $p_{\mathcal{X}}$ which partitions the set of subsequences; that is, letting $\mathcal{X}=\{j: p_j<p_{\mathcal{X}}\}$, $|\mathcal{X}|=\gamma n$ with $\gamma\in(0,1)$ a test parameter. We assume that the draws are independent across subsequences.

The fact that the sums of the subsequences $s_j=\sum_{i=(j-1)m+1}^{jm}x_i$ are drawn from binomial distribution yields the following alternative statement of the hypotheses:

$$H_0: s_j\sim \text{Binomial}(p,m), 1\leq j \leq n/m\\
H_1:s_j\sim \text{Binomial}(p_j,m)~\text{and there exists}~p_{\mathcal{X}}~\text{such that}~\mathcal{X}=\{j: p_j<p_{\mathcal{X}}\}, |\mathcal{X}|=\gamma n$$

Is there a statistical test between these two hypotheses given a parameter $\gamma$?  We know $n$ to be very large, order of hundreds of millions, $m$ is also large, order of tens of thousands, $p$ and $p_j$'s are unknown, but small (order of $10^{-4}$ so zeros are prevalent).  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

There are a variety of tests used in this circumstance.

The most commonly used test in this situation is a chi-square test.

It's essentially testing for homogeneity of proportions.

You can write the counts as a $2\times\frac{n}{m}$ table of counts (notionally 'successes' and 'failures' vs the $n/m$ groups) on which you carry out the usual chi-square test.

Here's an example. The rows represent the subsequences and the columns '1's and '0's while the interior of the table are the counts for each combination:

```
       '1'    '0'
subseq  sc    fc
    1   1   12112
    2   1   12329
    3   0   11974
    4   1   12029
    5   4   12151
    6   3   12096
    7   1   12075
    8   0   11908
    9   0   11973
    10  0   12043
    11  1   11985
    12  2   12138
    13  0   12241
    14  2   12036
    15  2   11803
```

A chi-square test of homogeneity works like a [chi-square test of independence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test#Test_of_independence).

Software will carry this test out, but it's simple enough to do:

1. We compute expected values for each count as the product of the marginal totals over the overall total: $E_{i,j}=R_i\cdot C_j/N$

For the small table above, the expected counts are:

```
  1.205200 12111.79
  1.226791 12328.77
  1.191370 11972.81
  1.196942 12028.80
  1.209379 12153.79
  1.203807 12097.80
  1.201519 12074.80
  1.184804 11906.82
  1.191271 11971.81
  1.198236 12041.80
  1.192564 11984.81
  1.207887 12138.79
  1.217936 12239.78
  1.197738 12036.80
  1.174555 11803.83
```

Then we compute $\sum_{i,j} \frac{(O_{ij}-E_{ij})^2}{E_{ij}}$, where $O_{ij}$ are the observed counts in the first table and $E_{ij}$ are the expected counts in the second table.

That sum is the chi-squared statistic. Under the null hypothesis, this test statistic has a chi-squared distribution (approximately). It has degrees of freedom equal to $(n_r-1)(n_c-1)$ where $n_c$ is the number of rows and $n_r$ is the number of columns. Since $n_c=2$, for your data it's one fewer than the number of subsequences.

Under the conditions you described, the expected count in the first (i.e. '**1**'s) column will typically be close to 1. Some programs will warn against using the chi-square in this situation, but with so many rows, the distribution of the test statistic should be very well approximated by the nominal chi-square distribution.

For the above data, the chi-squared statistic is 16.92, the df = (15-1)(2-1) = 14, and the p-value is 0.2607

You might find it useful to identify the most unusual cells - those with large values of $\frac{O_i-E_i}{\sqrt{E_i}}$ (either large positive or large negative, though with small expected values, large negative values won't occur).

Comment: Sorry, I just updated the question, but I think your answer might still work. (might it even be simplified to a $2\times 2$ table?)  However, I am not familiar with the use of the chi-square test for this purpose (I've used it in the past to test for independence...)

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying with your update.

Comment: Hmmm....  I may have made things more complicated with the update.  Basically, I am interested in finding out whether a substantial number of subsequences is not identical (I can tolerate a few non-identical subsequences, but not too many).  I think your pointer to the chi-square test is what I need -- I gotta figure out how it works...

Comment: Oh, that's different -- that sounds more like classification or estimation, or even perhaps a particular form of equivalence testing. I can expand on the chi-square test, but your question now sounds different.

Comment: I've given my problem a lot of thought, and I think that what I need is simply testing the null defined in $H_0$ against an alternate that $s_j$'s come from a different distribution. I think that I can use chi-square test for this, but still not completely sure how (though I should be able to figure it out after a night of sleep). One issue is that $p$ is unknown. Since the chi-squared test seems to testing the goodness of fit to a specific binomial, can I estimate $p$ from the data? And should I re-write my original question to reflect my thoughts? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: The chi-square I described in my answer tests for consistency of $p$ across groups (subsequences), not some prespecified $p$ (*homogeneity*, not *goodness-of-fit*). I will give some more details. (If you post a toy example, I can do something with that.)